# Texas - State and Local Highways

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, symbology

Is there a style set out there that has state shields for labeling highways? For example: one of the labels has the Interstate Highway symbol, but is there a style set that is state specific, such as FM roads or Texas State Highway roads?

Comment: What software are you using?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. Please edit your question to include a single question. Remember, you can always ask another question if needed. This helps keep things focused on the site and helps make questions usable for future readers.

Comment: Question has been reworded. I'm using Arcgis 10.4.1

Comment: You can find symbols for most (maybe all) state-specific highway sign designs here: https://github.com/VerdantSkys/DDVs_ALL/. If this is reopened I'll submit an answer, but long story short: these were originally created by someone who went by "DDV" online, if you search "DDV highway symbols" you can learn more about them: http://www.jmossmanart.com/ddv/ddv.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can download highway symbol sets for every state in the US [here](https://github.com/VerdantSkys/DDVs_ALL/). Each set includes several `.TTF` files which will need to be installed on your PC, as well as `.STYLE` files for use in ArcGIS. Each set includes USDOT symbols as well as symbols customized to reflect the state-specific designs used along the roads in that state, and even some custom symbols for roads with their own logos, for example the Garden State Parkway in NJ:

[image]

Each set includes a PDF explaining the various fonts and styles included in the set.

These symbols were originally created by [Jim Mossman](http://www.jmossmanart.com/ddv/ddv.html) back in the ArcView 3.x days and were freely distributed under the name "Data Deja View" (DDV). His site mentions that "In 2005 ESRI acquired most of DDV's symbols." but I don't know what they did with them, they don't appear to be available from Esri.